# Swift URLSession DataTask Fails when the app enters the background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background):

> **Note**
>   You don’t have to do all background network activity with background sessions as described in this article. Apps that declare appropriate background modes can use default URL sessions and data tasks, just as if they were in the foreground.

I'm trying to use my DataTask with default session configuration and delegates (not completion handler) but my data task is always failing if I press the home button and switch back to the app again:

```
Task <A25361F9-CAC0-4FA8-8663-777E1C6878A2>.<2> load failed with error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <A25361F9-CAC0-4FA8-8663-777E1C6878A2>.<2>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x108f07b40 [0x1db6c1420]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bb68118e240000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask <A25361F9-CAC0-4FA8-8663-777E1C6878A2>.<2>"
```

What I tried: using the shared session with or without completion handler, same problem.

My question is: what does this mean "Apps that declare appropriate background modes can use default URL sessions and data tasks"? How do you declare those background modes??

The only thing I came across is `UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask`

Is this what Apple means by "Appropriate background modes"? Or Am I missing something?

thank you

Comment: No, that is the correct approach. You can use `beginBackgroundTask` to get up to 180 seconds to complete your task.

Comment: @Paulw11 I can't find the 180 seconds number in the documentation, are you sure it's correct?

Comment: 180 seconds is the background time that is available to all iOS apps, but that value could change between releases at Apple's whim (but it has been 180 seconds for a number of years now); all you know for sure is that the `expirationHandler` you supply will be called shortly before your app runs out of time. If you don't end your background task when the expiration hander is called then iOS will kill your app.

Comment: You can also use [backgroundTimeRemaining](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623029-backgroundtimeremaining) to find out your remaining background time; be aware, however that when running under Xcode background time limits are not enforced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [`beginBackgroundTask(withName:expirationHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623051-beginbackgroundtask) is the correct way to request the OS to give your app a little time to finish requests it started before the user left the app. See [Extending Your App's Background Execution Time](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time).

> Is this what Apple means by “Appropriate background modes”?

They’re talking about any of the techniques that might have your app running in the background. See [About the Background Execution Sequence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/about_the_background_execution_sequence). And a “background task”, in which you’re given a finite amount of time to finish a task even though your app is no longer in the foreground, is one of those modes.

Another is [background fetch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh). If enabled, during background fetch, the OS may, at its sole discretion, fire up your app in the background, let you perform a request, and you then call the completion handler when it’s done. (In that case, you have even less than 3 minutes, something more like 30 seconds IIRC.) That is an example of an “appropriate background mode” for which you’d use a standard/default `URLSessionConfiguration`, not a background one. Apple makes a point of this because it would otherwise be easy to assume that any background-related network requests would require background `URLSessionConfiguration`. But that’s not the case.

So, if you’re just trying to let the app keep running a bit to finish the task even if the user hit the home button, then `beginBackgroundTask` in conjunction with a standard `URLSession` is adequate. Or if you happened to be using one of those “approved background modes” (which doesn’t sound like would be the situation in your case), then again, a standard `URLSession` is adequate.

A background `URLSession` is really for those cases where request may take longer than the allotted time. Perhaps you’re downloading many very large assets, such as a movies, that might take more than a few minutes. Only in that case do you need to use a background [`URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1407496-background). It just depends upon how long the request(s) will take.